# Can I specify default values in Blender for creating a new scene, object or material?

Tags: materials, objects, scene

How can I specify default values in Blender for creating a new scene or material?

In particular certain things bother me:

-I'd like a new scene to default to no units, not meters like has been added recently

-A Material I create I'd like backface culling to be automatically turned on

-When I create an object I'd like the *Normals > AutoSmooth* to default to actives

Is there any way of setting up Blender with these default settings?

Comment: for you first point, it's easy, you switch to Unit System > None then File > Defaults > Save Startup File

Comment: that doesn't work as when you add a new scene it will still choose meters, it's when you add a new scene to an existing file..... i can't see where you change this default value